# Codeginter - Pagination in reverse order

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Codegniter pagination library for pagination. Everything works fine. But I want pagination in reverse order.

```
For Ex : If there are 100 records, 10 records per page.
Right now first page display 1 to 10 records.
But I want first page should display 91 to 100 records. And second page will display 81 to 90 and so on.. 
Without changing the mysql Query.
'SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY id ASC'
```

What should I change in library.

Comment: Predicting code ............. Wait few Years ..

Comment: use `$this->db->order_by()`

Comment: I dont want records order by. I want pages in reverse manner.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with the ordering in the SQL, an idea rather than an answer: try using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), a jQuery plug-in.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Please elaborate my questions. My question is quite different from the comment which are given by other user.

Comment: Add codes to your question. And ping me. So will check is there anything i can do

Comment: Sir, you want pagination link in same order like page 1,2,3 .....or that to in reverse order like 99,98,97.... ????

Comment: pagination order must 1,2,3. but first page open last 10 records. order by id asc.

Comment: Why would you do that? It isn't logical. However you could get by `order id DESC` the 100 to 91 and maybe use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to order as 91-100.